# Python date generation not generating proper dates

Tags: python, date, if-statement, random

I'm a beginner at python and I made this random date generator which should generate year-month-date output. And 4,6,9,11 months have 30 days, all others 31.

But I'm having a problem where february in leap year still generates date=30 despite if and elif  having the condition where M must be 2.

```
import random
import calendar
for i in range(500):
    Y = rand.randint(0, 170)
    M = rand.randint(1, 12)
    
    if calendar.isleap(G+1850) == True and M == 2:
        D = rand.randint(1, 28)
    elif calendar.isleap(G+1850) == False and M == 2:
            D=rand.randint(1, 29)
    if M == 4 or M == 6 or M == 9 or M == 11:
            D=rand.randint(1, 30)
    else:
            D=rand.randint(1, 31)
```

Comment: did you mean to write `if calendar.isleap(Y+1850)` ?

Comment: Where is `rand` defined?

Comment: The final else-block is executed if "M == 2" and overwrites "D".

Comment: @MichaelButscher: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @ScottHunter Done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems mentioned in comments:

- you are using `rand` instead of `random`
- you are using `G` when presumably it should be `Y`

See a refactored code, rewriting the `if` statements to first test `M` then test `Y`.

```
import random
import calendar
for i in range(500):
    Y = random.randint(0, 170)
    M = random.randint(1, 12)
    
    if M == 2:
        if calendar.isleap(Y + 1850):
            Dmax = 28
        else:
            Dmax = 29
    elif M in [4, 6, 9, 11]:
        Dmax = 30
    else:
        Dmax = 31
        
    D = random.randint(1, Dmax)
    
    print(Y, M, D)
```

---

A more pythonic way would be to use `timedelta` to create a random date from the origin.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def random_date(start: datetime, end: datetime):
    days = (end - start).days
    return start + timedelta(days=random.randint(0, days))
    
    
start = datetime(1850, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2020, 12, 31)

for i in range(500):
    print(random_date(start, end))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. At first I tried the algorithmic way of generating dates hence why I didn't 100% use built in functions .

Answer (score 3):

The final else-block is executed if `M == 2` and overwrites `D`.

Simple solution can be to reorder the two if parts:

```
import random as rand
import calendar
for i in range(500):
    G = rand.randint(0, 170)
    M = rand.randint(1, 12)
    
    if M == 4 or M == 6 or M == 9 or M == 11:
        D=rand.randint(1, 30)
    else:
        D=rand.randint(1, 31)

    if calendar.isleap(G+1850) == True and M == 2:
        D = rand.randint(1, 28)
    elif calendar.isleap(G+1850) == False and M == 2:
        D=rand.randint(1, 29)
```